# Get all 4 timestamps in Python on Btrfs

Tags: python, file, timestamp, btrfs

If I do a `stat` command on a file under Btrfs, I get something like the following output:

```
Access: 2020-03-10 14:52:58.095399291 +1100
Modify: 2020-02-21 02:36:29.595148361 +1100
Change: 2020-02-21 17:20:59.692104719 +1100
 Birth: 2020-02-20 17:59:44.372828264 +1100
```

How do I get the 4 times in Python?

I tried doing `os.stat()`, however birth time doesn't exist there. I found [crtime](https://github.com/kootenpv/crtime) in past answers, but that requires `sudo`, which `stat` doesn't.

I could parse `stat` results myself, but ideally there is something that already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution calling the `stat` command & parsing the output manually. Please feel free to post solutions that don't require doing this.

```py
import datetime
import re
import subprocess

def stat_ns(path):
    '''
    Python doesn't support nanoseconds yet, so just return the total # of nanoseconds.
    '''
    # Use human-readable formats to include nanoseconds
    outputs = subprocess.check_output(['stat', '--format=%x\n%y\n%z\n%w', path]).decode().strip().split('\n')
    res = {}
    for name, cur_output in zip(('access', 'modify', 'change', 'birth'), outputs):
        # Remove the ns part and process it ourselves, as Python doesn't support it
        start, mid, end = re.match(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.(\d{9}) ([+-]\d{4})', cur_output).groups()
        seconds = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{start} {end}', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z').timestamp())
        ns = 10**9 * seconds + int(mid)
        res[name] = ns
    return res
```

Ah example output of the function looks like:

```
{'access': 1583824344829877823,
 'modify': 1583824346649884067,
 'change': 1583824346649884067,
 'birth': 1583813803975447216}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the `stat` output, I would suggest to use the [Python/C API](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/c-api/index.html) to directly interface the [`stat` source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/stat.c) as if it was a library.

It might be interesting to provide with an example, but I won't do it (at least for now) since I didn't play with the Python/C API for a long time and I'm currently busy with something else. I might challenge myself with that and update this answer later if ever I feel motivated.